# Can I find duplicate songs with different names?

Tags: software-recommendation, duplicate

I have so many duplicate songs but they have different names. Is there an application I can used to find and delete the duplicates?

Comment: The fdupes program lists duplicates by content, but with music, you'll need something that does fingerprinting of the audio

Comment: Could be done with reading the metadata of the files, although that would only work if the files were tagged properly in the first place. A bit of Python with a suitable ID3 library would do the job.

Comment: some ideas, search by title/artist in ID3 info, orsearch by file MD5 hash. however, when i wanted to do the same thing i reasoned it was best to keep the dupes because va compilations will be broken, albums of greatest hits vs another album by artist will be broken etc.mp3's are relatively small.

Answer (score 5):

there are discussions on this matter on community.metabrainz.org going on (see https://community.metabrainz.org/t/how-can-i-remove-all-of-my-duplicate-music/20495/8 for example).

additionally a wiki page on wiki.musicbrainz.org is showing an example on how you could find some duplicates:

https://wiki.musicbrainz.org/History:Find_Duplicate_Music_Files

This wiki boils down to get the deprectated libtunepimp (https://wiki.musicbrainz.org/History:libtunepimp/Download), install it and use the included `trm` util in the following script:

```
find / -regex '.*\(ogg\|mp3\|wav\)' -exec trm '{}' ';' -print0 
   | tr '\n\000' ' \n' 
   | sort 
   | uniq -c -W1 
   | grep -v -e '^ *1' 
   | cut -b9-44 
   | xargs -iXX -n1 grep XX /tmp/trms.log 
 > /tmp/trmdupls.log
```

in `/tmp/trmdupls.log` *should* be a list of all those duplicates. You should make **sure** there are no false positives in there before deleting all those files blindly.

Comment: as TRM is long deprecated, relying on it is not recommended. I did not find a solution using AcoustID, though there should be a way.